# Usar WHERE que funcione com clausula AND e a clausula OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com uma dúvida referente a lógica.
Tenho uma folha de orçamento que pode ter 3 status validando pelas linhas do pedido:

campos:
Linestatus = estatus da linha Fechado ou aberto
TrgetEntry = NULL se não há destino(nota fiscal) ou TrgetEntry = 1234 (Nº da NF)

Produto pendente de entrega: linestatus = 'O' AND TrgetEntry NULL
Produto Entregue: linestatus = 'C' AND TrgetEntry  1234
Desistencia do produto: linestatus = 'C' AND TrgetEntry NULL

Eu usei tentei usar o `WHERE` com `AND` e `OR`, mas o `OR` ignora qlqr sentença do `AND`

TRECHO da dúvida:

```
--Essa validação é pra trazer as linhas que foram entregues
WHERE LineStatus = 'C'
AND CANCELED = 'N' --OK
AND TrgetEntry IS NOT NULL
```

```
--E essa validação é pra trazer as linhas que estão em aberto, ou seja, que ainda não foram entregues  
WHERE LineStatus = 'O'
AND CANCELED = 'N' --OK
AND TrgetEntry IS NULL
```

E ao imprimir o pedido de venda, quero que me traga apenas o que está em aberto ou se o pedido estiver fechado, me traga todas as linhas entregues, mas não vejo como.

**Obs: O que diferencia do produto entregue para o produto cancelado é o TrgetEntry**

Meu código:

```
WHERE NUM.DOCUMENTO = 12456 
AND T1.LineStatus = (SELECT T1.LineStatus 
                        WHERE T1.LineStatus = 'O' AND TrgetEntry IS NOT NULL
                        OR T1.LineStatus = 'C' --ACHEI QUE O SQL IGNORARIA APENAS O QUE VEM ANTES DO OR COMO SE LESSE DE CIMA PRA BAIXO LINHA A LINHA
                        AND T0.DocStatus = 'C' 
                        AND TrgetEntry IS NOT NULL)
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a sanar essa dúvida?

Comment: A sua cláusula `WHERE` pode ser lida de várias maneiras, e a maneira como você está lendo não é a mesma que o SQL usa. Os `AND` são resolvidos antes do `OR`. Use parênteses e deixe claro como agrupar as condições.

Comment: como o @bfavaretto comentou, organize as condições entre parênteses,e use `OR` entre elas, assim por exemplo `WHERE (LineStatus = 'C' AND .... ) OR (LineStatus = 'O' AND ....)`